# How to send parameter List<string> from rdlc file to static method in customer assembly

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I use object datasource in my reporting services .rdlc file.
One of the properties in the object is of type `List<string>`.
I try to send this as a parameter to a static method in a custom assembly like this:

```
=MyModule.ReportCode.GetListItemString(Fields!TestList.Value,0)
```

but it does not work, I only get "`#error`".

Does anyone know what I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can work on the entire Fields collection and extract your list inside your custom assembly.

Yoo can create a function in your assembly like:

```
public static double MyFunction(Fields pFields)
```

and access the columns using :

```
if (pFields["myColum"] != null && pFields["myColum"].Value != null) ...
```

In the report you can call the function using :

```
Code.MyModule.MyFunction(Fields)
```

Remember to link the Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel assembly.

Hope it helps..