# Rdlc: Problems passing objects to a custom assembly in .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, rdlc, .net-assembly

Until recently we used `ReportViewer 9.0` in a `.Net 3.5` environment. All our reports use businessobjects as datasource and are processed locally.

Most of our businessobjects have a property Self returning the entire object.
For special processing a call to a custom assembly is used passing the entire businessobject using the Self property as in

```
=reporting.ReportFunction.ValueOf(Fields!Self.Value, "sometext")
```

Moving to `ReportViewer 11.0` in a `.Net 4` environment we ran into problems with the aforementioned construction. Any ordinary property of the businessobjects can be passed to functions like `ValueOf` giving proper results. But using an expression like the one with `Self` leads to the dreadful `#Error` in the resulting report; `ValueOf` is never called using the `Self` property.

Is this functionality broken? Or is it a security issue? Does anyone know if and how passing an entire object to a custom assembly can be done using `ReportViewer 11.0` and `.Net 4`?
A suggestion in [How to send parameter List<string> from rdlc file to static method in customer assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793595/how-to-send-parameter-liststring-from-rdlc-file-to-static-method-in-customer-a) to pass the Fields property doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanx in advance, Jan.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out in .Net 4 the report is executed in another app domain by default. .Net Remoting is used to get data from the current app domain to the 'other side'. To communicate objects with .Net Remoting these objects must be serializable.

Adding the `[Serializable]` attribute to classes and properties in my application solved the `#Error` problem.

See also [this site](http://wraithnath.blogspot.nl/2011/04/reportviewer-object-datasource-nested.html).